# (gtk:4783): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf: assertion 'GTK_IS_IMAGE (image)' failed

Tags: c++, image, gtk, refresh, destroy

This is my code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h>

void destroy(void) {
    gtk_main_quit();
}


int main()
{
    GdkPixbuf* buf;
    GdkPixbuf* buf2;
    GError* err = NULL;
    int a=0, i=0, j=0;

    GtkWidget* window;
    GtkWidget *image =0;

    gtk_init (NULL,NULL);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    buf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file("1.jpg", &err);
    buf2 = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file("2.jpg", &err);

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if((i%2)==0)
        {
            gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(image), buf);

            for(j=0; j<10000; j++)
            {}
        }
        else
        {
            gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(image), buf2);
            for(j=0; j<10000; j++)
            {}
        }

        g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT (window), "destroy",
        G_CALLBACK (destroy), NULL);
        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), image);
        gtk_widget_show_all(window);
        gtk_main();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the result:

```
(gtk:4783): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf: assertion 'GTK_IS_IMAGE (image)' failed

(gtk:4783): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_add: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
^C
```

What I am trying to do is : I have 2 images, and a loop that I want to show one image for odd numbers and other image for even numbers.
But this simple task seems very hard to do! please help me to correcting my code...thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create a new GtkImage just to change an image. Juste create a simple GtkWindow with an GtkImage inside. No if/else like you're doing that duplicates code. Then load the image you want to display in a `GdkPixbuf`, which is the objet that really stores the pixel data. This is done using `gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file`, and helps you keep around the image data in case you want to show it again (caching). Then you use `gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf` to ask the GtkImage to change the image it displays.

About your interactive loop: you can't do that unless you create/destroy the whole UI each time you're asked a new number, which is not a refresh. What you need to do is either:

- ask the user the numbers of all the frames you want to display, and
  *then*, create the window and stuff and run the gtk main loop.
- or better, use a timeout event source using `g_timeout_add` that will create regularly call a callback where you'll be able to increment a frame counter. Use this counter to get the appropriate image, and call `gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf` or `gtk_image_set_from_file`.

Comment: You didn't declare buf2. Then, to cast a GtkWidget to GtkImage, use the `GTK_IMAGE()` macro.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work yet! It only gets the first number from user and stuck with that image(I edited the code again)

Comment: No wonder it doesn't work, you barely followed my advice. What did you not understand in my comment so I can improve it?

Comment: Remove your `ggg` function which is useless, then in your `main` remove your interactive loop. Your `main` function should just create a window with a GtkImage in it, nothing more. This is where you should start.

Comment: But I want to show images respect to what user wants. It should be interactive.

Comment: If you want the interactivity, do it in the GTK+ user interface, not using a `scanf` in terminal mode. The two approaches are incompatible.

Comment: If I have a program and it has two states and those change during the execution,and I want to show an image respect to each state, should I use GTK interface? What's that?

Comment: Those states don't change magically I guess, since you want the user to interactively change them. What I'm saying is: don't interact with the user using the terminal and `scanf`. The whole purpose of a toolkit like GTK+ is to create graphical user interfaces which main purpose is to interact with the user.

Comment: You can use buttons to tell your program what you want to display, or a combo box, or a text entry, whatever. The whole point of these widgets is to get user input. The simplest approach for example would be to have one button for each image you want to display. Or one single button that changes the image everytime you click on it. Think of how a user would use your application in a sane way.

Comment: Dear friend, this is a part of my robot's program. my robot has two states, and I want if the robot changed the state it shows one of two images respect to it's state! I don't know GTK and don't want to write a graphical user interface...I only need 2 images for my robot states

Comment: I edited the whole of question again, maybe it's better now. consider the odd numbers as state one and even numbers for state 2 ...this is my real problem

Comment: How can I destroy the previous window and show a new one?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum to answer "how do I do this?", it's supposed to answer very specific questions, which can't be the case if you change and change again the question. If you have more precise questions, just ask a new question.

Comment: As I said previously, you *can't* do what you're doing this way. GTK+ is like most toolkits, event-driven. You can't do a for loop in your main were you change UI elements and hope it will work: it can't.

Comment: What I need to know is how and when your states changes. This is how the key to know how to trigger the events that will change the user interface. And yes, something inside a window, even if it's just an image is a user interface, even if it's a very simple one.

Comment: BTW, your current bug is that you try to set a pixbuf on a GtkImage but you didn't create the GtkImage in the first place.  You wrote `GtkWidget *image =0;` . You're supposed to write `GtkWidget *image = gtk_image_new();` instead.

Comment: My final answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47791066/518853 . You probably won't need it now, but I've also written a sample GTK+  application that displays images in a timer-based loop: https://github.com/liberforce/gtk-samples/blob/master/gtk3/c/gtk3-frames/main.c . The images need to be placed in the same directory as the binary.

Comment: That "final answer" isn't really relevant anymore (question was deleted). As for the sample code, the correct link is now: https://github.com/liberforce/gtk-samples/blob/master/c/gtk3-frames/main.c